# Downloadable WPF tutorial

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2008

I'm flying to New Zealand next week and figured that it would be a good chance to learn the basics of WPF. I've been flicking through [this](http://www.wpftutorial.net/XAML.html) tutorial which seems really good but there is a lack of wifi in the stratosphere. Does any one know of a similar, easily downloadable tutorial for WPF or do I need to save all the pages on the website to my laptop one by one :(

Thanks,
Patrick

EDIT: The MVVM pattern looks very useful so I would like a tutorial which covers implmenting MVVM in some detail if possible too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while back, [Jaime Rodriguez](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/default.aspx) and [Karl Shifflett](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/) hosted a WPF training tour.  The latest PowerPoint slides and code samples are available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2009/06/16/thanks-chicago-here-is-the-content.aspx).  Plenty of MVVM information is included.

In addition, there are a bunch of [WPF Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples) on MSDN that you can download.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of good books on the subject by Apress (I have both sitting on my desk) and they're available to buy as ebooks.

[Foundations of WPF](http://apress.com/book/view/9781590597606) and [Pro WPF in C# 2008](http://apress.com/book/view/1590599551)

They might not be the cheapest option, but they are good resources.

Comment: Thanks Zombie. Which would you recommend for a competent programmer with next to no knowledge of WPF. It also seems the MVVM pattern is useful with WPF, is one better than the other at teaching MVVM?

Comment: As a competent programmer, you should be able to dive straight into the pro book.  To be honest, I use the book as a reference more than a tutorial, but I've just had a look and it does go from very simple first principles.  Google books have a limited preview at http://books.google.com/books?q=pro+wpf+in+c%23&btnG=Search+Books if you fancy checking it out...

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.rubensteins.nl/index.php?entry=entry080221-154055